# Is it possible to access the parent data context of a template loaded using Blaze.render()?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I load a template in a bootbox using `Blaze.render()` or `Blaze.renderWithData()`:

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.myTemplate, 
                     {"arg1":false, "arg2":"blabla"}, 
                     $("#dialogAnchor")[0]);
```

While it is usually possible to access directly parent data context using `Template.parentData()` in a template loaded with spacebars (e.g. `{{> myTemplate}}`), it is not possible to do the same when using `Blaze.render()` or `Blaze.renderWithData()`

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now familiar with this problem and since no one answered, here is how I deal with it:

First, a template added to the page using `Blaze.render()` or `Blaze.renderWithData()` will have no `Template.parentData()` context.

As a workaround, it is still possible to pass it as an argument, like this:

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.myTemplate, {parentDataContext: Template.currentData()})
```

However, note that **it will not be reactive**.

If you need reactivity, there is another workaround. You can store the context elements that you want to share in a `ReactiveDict()` (not a `ReactiveVar()`) and pass it too as an argument:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
  this.dataContext = new ReactiveDict()
  this.dataContext.set("contextVariable1", this.data.whatever)
  this.dataContext.set("contextVariable2", this.data.ImAwesome)
  // etc.
  Blaze.renderWithData(Template.myTemplate, {parentDataContext: this.dataContext})
}
```

This way, you can share a reactive local context between a parent template and a child template loaded using `Blaze.render()` or `Blaze.renderWithData()`.